# What are the requirements to receive Tracking Data from Journey Builder in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, history-tracking

I'm creating journeys in my MID and I realised that not all the journeys are pushing tracking data into Salesforce. I checked with MC Support and they checked that everything is working as expected but they didn't provide any documentation about what are the requirements for a journey to push tracking data into Salesforce.

Does anyone know these requirements?

Comment: "Tacking" being Individual Email Results records? You're getting some, but not all? Generally, tracking gets pushed back automatically, if you're injecting sendable objects into your journey. I What are you sending to in your journeys? Contacts, Accounts, Users, Leads, Opportunities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sending emails fro Journey Builder, you need to check the "Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud" checkbox, regardless whether you are using Sales Cloud Data or a data extension as the entry source:

[image]

You, of course, need to use the contact/lead ID as your subscriber key and Marketing Cloud Connect has to be connected properly.